# iPhone peer to peer via wifi?

Tags: iphone, networking, wifi, adhoc, peer

Scenario:

In a Campsite, iPhone/iPods in different camp can connect, chat or share photos.
I want to use wifi not bluetooth.

Since there is no wifi internet around. One of the iPod should work as an wifi access point, like the concept in "wifi-direct", is it possible?

Can iOS networking library do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you're looking for is called "WiFi Direct" (http://www.wi-fi.org/Wi-Fi_Direct.php). there's no reason why an iPhone couldn't support it, but it doesn't yet.

Comment: I'm doing a research, my supervisor want me to examine if p2p via wifi on iPhone is possible. so is it iphone hare ware not supporting adhoc mode wifi ?

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 adds the [Multipeer Connectivity Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/Introduction/Introduction.html) for exactly this purpose.